# Region growing Vs Clustering

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

In image processing, how region growing and clustering differ from each other ? Give more information on how they differ. Thank you for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Region growing :** 
You have to select seed points and then the local area around the seed is analyzed in order to know if the neighbor pixels should have the same label. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_growing
It can be used for precise image segmentation.

**Clustering :**
There are many clustering techniques ([k-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), hierarchical clustering, density clustering, etc.). Clustering algorithms don't ask to input seed points because they are based on unsupervised learning.
It can be use for coarse image segmentation.

Comment: In clustering (k-means) also, we have to select the k-means in the initialization right? here mean values are like seed points right ? please explain

Comment: No, k-means are initialized randomly, then the k centroids will iteratively converge.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: One more question, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_clustering in the above link , I do not understand the paragraph after the standard function. Is it typo error?

Answer (score 0):

I found region growing similar to some clustering algorithm. I explained my view point below:

***In region growing there are 2 cases:***

1. Selecting seed points randomly which is similar to k-mean. seeds
   play the role of means here. Then, we start with one seed and spread
   it until we cannot grow it anymore (like we start with one mean and
   we continue till we reach a convergence). and the way we grow the
   region is based on the euclidean distance form seed grey value
   (usually).
2. Second case in region growing can be considered with no seed (assume
   we don't know how many seeds to choose or we don't know the number
   of clusters). So we start with the first pixel. Then we find
   neighbors of current pixel with considering distance d from mean
   grey value of the region (of course at first iteration mean grey
   value is exactly current grey value). Afterwards, we update the mean
   grey value. In this way region growing seems to act like mean shift
   algorithm. If we don't update mean grey value after each assigning,
   then it could be considered as a DBSCAN algorithm.